# How to fetch nodes with different labels in one query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have three types of nodes:

```
(:Meal), (:User), (:Dish)
```

With relationships:

```
(:Meal)<-[:JOIN]-(:User), (:Meal)<-[:ORDERED]-(:Dish)
```

Now I want to fetch the information of meal in one query. I want to get result like this:

```
id: 1
name: xxx,
users: [1,2,3,4],
dishes: [23,42,42]
```

where *users* and *dishes* fields contains the ids of those users and dishes.

I tried:

```
MATCH (meal:Meal)
OPTIONAL MATCH (meal)<-[:JOIN]-(user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (meal)<-[:ORDERED]-(dish:Dish)
RETURN id(meal), meal.name, COLLECT(ID(user)), COLLECT(ID(dish))
```

However, this query will generate a lot duplication of users and dishes. If there are N users and M dishes, it will match N*M user-dish pairs.

I do realize that I can use DISTINCT to remove duplication. However, I am not sure about the efficiency of such query.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

Try to separate the different parts of your query using `WITH`:

```
MATCH (meal:Meal)
OPTIONAL MATCH (meal)<-[:JOIN]-(user:User)
WITH meal, collect(ID(user)) as users
OPTIONAL MATCH (meal)<-[:ORDERED]-(dish:Dish)
RETURN id(meal), meal.name, users, COLLECT(ID(dish)) as dishes
```